# JavaFX 8 ant build error code too large

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, javafx, build.xml

I am developing on eclipse; my code currently compiles and runs find directly from eclipse (By performing Run As Java Application) - I have not encountered any errors in this process.

I have then attempted to generate the Ant build.xml and tried to compile it, this terminates with a `BUILD FAILED`; below is the output of the build:

```
Buildfile: C:\App-Path\build\build.xml
setup-staging-area:
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\App-Path\build\externalLibs
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\App-Path\build\project
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\App-Path\build\projectRefs
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\App-Path\build\externalLibs
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\App-Path\build\externalLibs
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\App-Path\build\externalLibs
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\App-Path\build\externalLibs
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\App-Path\build\externalLibs
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\App-Path\build\externalLibs
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\App-Path\build\externalLibs
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\App-Path\build\externalLibs
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\App-Path\build\externalLibs
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\App-Path\build\externalLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\App-Path\build\project
     [copy] Copying 59 files to C:\App-Path\build\project
     [copy] Copied 22 empty directories to 2 empty directories under C:\App-Path\build\project
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\App-Path\build\projectRefs
do-compile:
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\App-Path\build\build
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\App-Path\build\build\src
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\App-Path\build\build\libs
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\App-Path\build\build\classes
     [copy] Copying 9 files to C:\App-Path\build\build\libs
     [copy] Copying 59 files to C:\App-Path\build\build\src
     [copy] Copied 21 empty directories to 2 empty directories under C:\App-Path\build\build\src
    [javac] Compiling 29 source files to C:\App-Path\build\build\classes
    [javac] C:\App-Path\build\build\src\com\stt3\types\IcomoonUltimatePack.java:60: error: code too large
    [javac]         HOME('\ue900'),
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] Note: C:\App-Path\build\build\src\com\stt3\test\YQLParser.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 1 error

BUILD FAILED
C:\App-Path\build\build.xml:107: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 3 seconds
```

The Class that seems to be generating the error is simply an adaptation of the existing code for the JavaFX FontAwesome Glyph class (definition [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.controlsfx/controlsfx/8.0.2/org/controlsfx/glyphfont/FontAwesome.java)) for the IcoMoon glyph set (around 2000 glyphs/character associations).

Here is the link to the code for the offending class: https://gist.github.com/autronix/51322d3c24f21e6755a5

Since the code is compiling and running fine in eclipse directly, I am wondering if I have missed any parameters in the ant compiler. I haven't been able to figure out how to solve this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods in Java are restricted to **64k** of byte code. Once you exceed the limit the java compiler will throw an error

```
error: code too large
```

All static initializations are done in a single method, so there is a possibility it is happening because of this.

It runs fine in eclipse because eclipse has its own compiler.

If you want to read more about it, [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/help-bison@gnu.org/msg01990.html) is a nice thread.